# Rails associations are not associated correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The goal of this is to have the comment belong to article which belongs to user:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :profile
  has_many :articles, -> {order 'published_at DESC, title ASC'}, dependent: :nullify          
  has_many :replies, through: :articles, source: :comments
end
```

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  validates :title, :body, presence: true 

  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
  has_many :comments

  def long_title
    "#{title} - #{published_at}"
  end
end
```

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :article
end
```

What i get back from console is:

```
 irb(main):048> user.replies
=> []
```

but!

```
 irb(main):049> user.replies.all
  Comment Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" INNER JOIN "articles" ON "comments"."article_id" = "articles"."id" WHERE "articles"."user_id" = ? ORDER BY published_at DESC, title ASC  [["user_id", 3]]
=> 
[#<Comment:0x0000ffff802d1420
  id: 1,
  article_id: 1,
  name: "guest",
  email: "guest@email.com",
  body: "comment text",
  created_at: Tue, 03 Oct 2023 22:05:04.136672000 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Tue, 03 Oct 2023 22:05:04.136672000 UTC +00:00>]
```

Can someone explain why user.replies is empty but .all shows.

When i return just Articles.last.comments (there is only 1 comment and article) It returns the comment fine. So why is the articles not handing that up to the user when I ask for it?

Comment: Could you add the code before your first call to `user.replies`? There's no SQL printout meaning the association has been already loaded. If you added replies through another object, the new replies will not show up automatically as you do not have `inverse_of` specified on your associations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably due to [ActiveRecord query caching](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#sql-caching).

In your console, you've probably called `user.replies` first, added a comment from the UI, and then called `user.replies` from the console. So the console just returned the cached value. If you notice, there is no SQL statement (i.e. `Comment Load ...`) before the result in returned.

When you ran `user.replies.all`, you can see the SQL statement being printed out.

You can try to run `user.reload` first, and then `user.replies`, and you should get the same result as when calling `user.replies.all`.

You will probably only encounter this issue in the console. Console is good for initial testing, but it is best to do the testing in the browser and/or via automated test to check the actual behaviour of your request.